# Visual Studio for Mac download very slow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

Have been trying my best to install Visual Studio for Mac, but installer download speed is shockingly slow. Anyone have an idea why this is, and how to get past it.

Download speed: Avg 32,0 KB/s
If I download anything else I get about 400 KB/s.
Tried to download Xamarin Studio, and same issue, extremely slow. If I download just Mono framework, normal download Speed 400 KB/s.

Tried to find an offline copy of VS for Mac, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a number of retries, a manual retry option becomes available. That should sort out the issue.

Comment: what does manual retry mean? im having this same issue, its super annoying

Comment: This means I had to manually download the individual apps needed instead of going through the installer. This should be resolved by now.

Answer (score -1):

Quit & restart installing, it becomes faster.

Ofcourse, it resumes and downloads faster from that point..

:)